# Wordpress search rewriting

Tags: url-rewriting, search

I have redirected search page to new pretty URL, but that page now shows error 404. What extra code do I have to add to deal with URL on that error page.

Here is my code so far:

```
function change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if( isset( $_GET['search_lat'] ) || isset( $_GET['search_lng'] ) || isset( $_GET['search_city'] ) )
    {
        $new_uri    = array( );

        if( isset( $_GET['search_lat'] ) && strlen( $_GET['search_lat'] ) )
        {
            $new_uri[]  = urlencode( 'lat-'.$_GET['search_lat'] );
        }

        if( isset( $_GET['search_lng'] ) && strlen( $_GET['search_lng'] ) )
        {
            $new_uri[]  = urlencode( 'lng-'.$_GET['search_lng'] );
        }

        if( isset( $_GET['sort'] ) && strlen( $_GET['sort'] ) )
        {
            $new_uri[]  = urlencode( 'sort-'.$_GET['sort'] );
        }

        if( isset( $_GET['search_city'] ) && strlen( $_GET['search_city'] ) )
        {
            $new_uri[]  = urlencode( 'city-'.$_GET['search_city'] );
        }

        if( isset( $_GET['search_category'] ) && strlen( $_GET['search_category'] ) )
        {
            $new_uri[]  = urlencode( 'category-'.$_GET['search_category'] );
        }

        if( isset( $_GET['search_type'] ) && strlen( $_GET['search_type'] ) )
        {
            $new_uri[]  = urlencode( 'type-'.$_GET['search_type'] );
        }

        if( isset( $_GET['search_neighborhood'] ) && strlen( $_GET['search_neighborhood'] ) )
        {
            $new_uri[]  = urlencode( 'neighborhood-'.$_GET['search_neighborhood'] );
        }

        wp_redirect( home_url( "/properties-search-results-2/" ) . implode( '/' , $new_uri ) );

        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

**EDIT:**

I have added the following code in functions.php file of the theme, but still not working.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(   "properties-search-results-2/category-([^/]*)/city-([^/]*)/lat-([^/]*)/lng-([^/]*)/neighborhood-([^/]*)/sort-([^/]*)/type-([^/]*)/?" ,
                        '?page_id=16&search_lat=$matches[3]&search_lng=$matches[4]&sort=$matches[6]&search_city=$matches[2]&search_category=$matches[1]&search_type=$matches[7]&search_neighborhood=$matches[5]' ,
                        'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Comment: you need to [add rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to handle new URL patterns.

Comment: I have updated the question.